# How do I install and start a unity desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, unity, xorg

I have a plain Ubuntu terminal in a website:

[image: Ubuntu Terminal]

It has nothing (and I mean nothing), beyond what is needed to run terminal with the bash shell. I am trying to see what it is capable of, I just do not know how to get a desktop on it.

I have tried

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

when I do that, it installs and then does nothing. What else do I need to do?
Also, what would I need to do if this was a normal Ubuntu computer?

Comment: I don't think that is possible from that terminal, if it is, ask the owners to help!

Comment: Try `startx` but as said that might not work..

Comment: I tried Startx but nothing happened, it gave the error: Bash: startx: command not found.

Comment: Whatever you see on that website is not Ubuntu. It may behave similar to Ubuntu or even be based on Ubuntu but it lacks many of the features of an actual Ubuntu installation. I'm therefore voting to keep this question closed. Also, please don't tack additional questions onto existing questions that broaded their scope significantly like yours just did. Instead, please [open a new question](/questions/ask). In this case you can probably find your answer in [How do I install Ubuntu?](/q/6328/175814) or [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](/q/221835/175814).

Comment: thank you im a new user so it was helpful to see why it was said that it was not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue reading on the left hand side, it has multiple pages, this terminal you see there is not supposed to be used to install a GUI on top of it, its plainly there so you can follow the steps provided in the tutorial.

Comment: the side menu is not a tutorial on the terminal there, the terminal isnt even used in the module. I just wanted to see how normal it was.

Comment: Its very limited terminal shell for a browser maybe backed by a small machine in their server park. You cant do much with it other than following the tutorial steps which where pretty basic in the part i could access without payment.